# Android:Error while upgrading Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0

Tags: android

I get this error while upgrading my Android Studio IDE from version 2.3.3 to 3.0.0

[image]

that's folder of my java installation:

[image]

any help, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your OS version?

Comment: Try an uninstall and then a fresh installation.

Comment: my OS is Windows 10

Comment: @Henry, I 'd like a short solution ,if exist of course.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio contains it's own JRE (`jre` subfolder within the Android Studio installation). The mentioned JRE files all belong to Android Studio.

Therefore you can safely delete the mentioned JRE files. It will not affect your system.

Comment: i resolved my problem by clicking on cancel button, then backup process is declenched of jre files,and i don't know if files are deleted automatically after.But i noticed that installed android studio 3.0.1  works know.